# sample or step by step tutorial on implementing azure ACS with Active Directory

Tags: azure, active-directory, asp.net-mvc-4, acs

I am looking for a ASP.NET (MVC), C# sample or step by step tutorial on how to implement Azure ACS with Active Directory.

Appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Do you need it to specifically be (hosted or on-premises) AD, as opposed to, say, Windows Azure Active Directory?

Answer (score 0):

Below are two simple suggestions

1. [Stack Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6061903/1557322)
2. [Microsoft Patterns and Practices](http://claimsid.codeplex.com/)